# Как передать std::min в std::transform?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Как передать `std::min` в `std::transform`? Выдаёт ошибку `no matching function for call to ...`

код:

```
std::transform(x.begin()+1,x.end(),y.begin(),y.begin()+1,std::min);
```

Comment: уже 2 раза написал 0 ответов

Comment: Изменение Вашего вопроса показывает близкий к правильному вариант оформления - Вы же постоянно меняете его - чего Вы хотите добиться?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::min` - не функция, а шаблон функции. Чтобы превратить шаблон функции в функцию, вам нужно его *специализировать*, то есть указать шаблонные аргументы

```
std::transform(x.begin()+1, x.end(), y.begin(), y.begin()+1, std::min<тип>);
```

Этого было бы уже достаточно в C++98. Однако в стандартной библиотеке C++11 и позже  `std::min` еще и перегружена для `std::initializer_list`, то есть `std::min<тип>` тоже не является *однозначным* указанием функции.

Чтобы из набора перегруженных функций выбрать одну конкретную придется еще применить `static_cast`

```
std::transform(x.begin()+1, x.end(), y.begin(), y.begin()+1,
  static_cast<const тип & (*)(const тип &, const тип &)>(std::min<тип>));
```

Явное указание шаблонных аргументов в такой ситуации не обязательно

```
std::transform(x.begin()+1, x.end(), y.begin(), y.begin()+1,
  static_cast<const тип & (*)(const тип &, const тип &)>(std::min));
```

Готово.

Как видите, овчинка не стоит выделки и смысла во всем этом практически никакого нет. `std::min` изначально не предназначена и не приспособлена для такого использования. Проще просто завернуть вызов `std::min` в лямбду.

Comment: Подставил int (x и y это векторы интов), но всё равно почему-то не компилируется

Comment: @брак: См. выше.

Answer (score 6):

Ну, `min` все же шаблон, а не функция...

Попробуйте через лямбду:

```
std::transform(x.begin()+1,x.end(),y.begin(),y.begin()+1,
               [](auto a, auto b){ return std::min(a,b); });
```

Но меня смущает, что у вас запись идет в перекрывающийся диапазон, а `transform` в общем случае не гарантирует определенный порядок обработки...

Еще раз - `std::min` - не функция, а шаблон. Вот если написать типа

```
int min(int x, int y) { return (x < y) ? x : y; }
...
std::transform(x.begin()+1,x.end(),y.begin(),y.begin()+1, min);
```

то все будет работать (подразумевая, что контейнеры содержат `int`ы).

P.S. О "лишних вызовах"... Вот во что превращает "вызов" лямбды VC++ 2017:

```
; 1500 :        *_UDest = _Func(*_UFirst1, *_UFirst2);

    mov ecx, DWORD PTR [esi]
    lea esi, DWORD PTR [esi+4]
    cmp ecx, DWORD PTR [edx]
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [edi+4]
    cmovge  ecx, DWORD PTR [edx]
    inc ebx
    mov DWORD PTR [edi-4], ecx
```

Как видите, никакого *вызова* тут нет вообще...

А вот во что `static_cast<const int & (*)(const int &, const int &)>(std::min)`:

```
; 1500 :        *_UDest = _Func(*_UFirst1, *_UFirst2);
    push    esi
    push    edi
    call    ??$min@H@std@@YAABHABH0@Z       ; std::min<int>
    add edi, 4
    lea ebx, DWORD PTR [ebx+4]
    add esp, 8
```

Таки в реальный вызов, что грустно...

Comment: Так это не std::min, а новая функция

Comment: Не нравится - придумывайте свой способ...

Comment: Отличный ответ!

Comment: Какой вопрос - такой и ответ. "Как заставить плавать брусок железа?" "Сделайте из него лодку". "Это уже будет не кусок железа!" ...

Comment: Брусок железа не является бинарной функцией в отличие от std::min --очередной отличный ответ

Comment: `min` не является **функцией**. Напишите **функцию** `min` - и все заработает :)

Comment: зависит от определения функции, тут является например https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/algorithm. Подобных определений брусков железа я не видел

Comment: Там написано четко, что это шаблон. Вобщем, я написал, как вам добиться своего проще всего. Допускаю существование какого-то хитровывернутого способа передать как функтор шаблон - но думаю, что проще, чем с лямбдой, это не будет. Засим дискуссию завершаю.

Comment: @брак Какая разница, новая это функция или нет? Работает ведь.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat чтобы не было двойного вызова например на ровном месте

Comment: @HolyBlackCat например std::less так можно передавать без обёрток, а std::min почему-то не компилируется

Comment: Потому что `less` - класс...

Comment: Если в варианте со `static_cast` компилятор сумел догадаться, что мы вызываем именно `std::min` (а не "какую-то" функцию через указатель), но при этом не сумел встроить этот вызов - это не более чем странная недоделка этого компилятора. Я бы ожидал другой проблемы в варианте со `static_cast`: вызова через указатель.

Comment: @AnT Скомпилировано с одинаковыми ключиками (полной) оптимизации...